# What is different about using Lodash and ES6 to deal with the Array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, node-modules

I want to compare using yarn module lodash with using protogenic ES6

I had a simple demo to see what can I get from they, and I got same thing from `foundArr1` and `foundArr2` by using `console.log`.

What is different between each others?

```
const Arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'foo',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'bar',
  }
]

const foundArr1 = Arr1.find(elememt => element.id === id);
const foundArr2 = _.find(Arr1, element => element.id === id);

console.log(foundArr1);
console.log(foundArr2);
```

Comment: What makes you think there's a difference?

Comment: @UnholySheep Cause my friend tell me `lodash` has higher efficiency, but I can't find any difference

Comment: If your friend believes that lodash has better performance he should be able to write a test-case to prove it

Comment: Lodash has nothing else up its sleeve than JavaScript, so there is no way it can be faster than plain (ES6 or not) JavaScript.

Comment: So Is there anythings ES6 can't do but Lodash can ?

Comment: @trincot https://jsperf.com/lodash-find-vs-array-find this testcase tell me `lodash` faster than ES6 in my system

Comment: I guess lodash uses a `for` loop, not `find`. It would be interesting to compare it with a `for` loop.

Comment: Because the implementations are different. Besides performance, browser developers have other things to care about. Underscore/Lodash sometimes can offer implementations that provide superior performance, because this is one of library's priorities. And sometimes it can't. Unless this is performance-critical place, using Lodash solely for this reason is premature optimization. Lodash or not, If a developer is after performance, it's his/her responsibility to run some tests to figure out the most performant way.